# Can a python class return a new instance of its class?

Tags: python, class

Is the following python code valid?

```
class Test:
  def __init__(self):
    self.number = 5

  def returnTest(self):
    return Test()
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes it is valid. The class is defined by the time you create an object and call the `returnTest` method.

```
In [2]: x = Test()

In [3]: y = x.returnTest()

In [4]: y
Out[4]: <__main__.Test instance at 0x1e36ef0>

In [5]:
```

However, in cases where a method acts like a factory, you might want to consider using the [classmethod](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#classmethod) decorator. When inheritance and other annoyances come in the way, this can help.

Answer (score 5):

When working with subclasses, I suggest using something more like this:

```
return type(self)(*args, **kwargs)
```

This ensures that the returned type is the same as the class returning it.

Here's a full example:

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.number = 5

    def returnTest(self):
        return type(self)()

class SubTest(Test):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.number = 6

t1 = Test()
t2 = SubTest()
print( type(t1.returnTest()), type(t2.returnTest()) )
```

Outputs:

```
<class '__main__.Test'> <class '__main__.SubTest'>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's valid.  `returnTest` will not be run until it is called.  It does not create an infinite loop, since the method is not called on the newly created object.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it works but it appears that returnTest() is always the same instance of Test.

```
class Test:
  def __init__(self):
    self.number = 5

  def returnTest(self):
    return Test()


t = Test()
print t
print t.returnTest()
print t.returnTest()


$ python te.py
<__main__.Test instance at 0xb72bd28c>
<__main__.Test instance at 0xb72bd40c>
<__main__.Test instance at 0xb72bd40c>
```

This is true for Python 2.7 and 3.2.  @classmethod didn't make a difference.  Interestingly enough, pypy returns a different instance each time:

```
$ pypy te.py
<__main__.Test instance at 0xb6dcc1dc>
<__main__.Test instance at 0xb6dcc1f0>
<__main__.Test instance at 0xb6dcc204>
```

Comment: Try storing the t.returnTest() result because if you don't do so, it may be garbage collected and it may seems to you that the same instance is returned but it's only the same address, recycled.

Comment: That's a great thought.  Storing off the results into a list continues to create different objects.

Comment: My +1 to kasyc. I am using Python 2.7.1 on Windows.  Without storing the reference, I can also observe the reuse/recycling of the garbage collected space mentioned by kasyc.

Comment: Actually that IS a great thought.  It is a matter of differing garbage collection routines between Pypy and Python 2.7/3.2.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. It's a valid python code. Many programming languages allow to return an instance of a class being defined. Think to the **singleton** pattern.